# Where can I ask about unsupported Ubuntu OS?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am trying to find out if there is a place within the Stack Exchange network where I can ask questions regarding an unsupported version of Ubuntu. I crafted a detailed post about dependencies and python on Ubuntu 16.04 but was dismissed by Ask Ubuntu members and mods because 16.04 is no longer supported.

I then tried to ask on Super User where I could ask about unsupported software and was dismissed and redirected here because that is the wrong type of question to ask there.

To be clear, I mean *anywhere*, not necessarily in the Stack Exchange network, but that is where I would start.

Comment: What's the actual question - broadly Ubuntu is in topic on super user

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ok. I will post it with all of its detail on SuperUser, and see what happens.

Comment: Related Q&As on Ask Ubuntu Meta about their policy on questions about EOL releases: [Should we allow questions that are about releases which are considered End of Life?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5611/1406746), [EOL Question Handling Discussion... again](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7457/1406746)

Answer (score 2):

- https://superuser.com/ (assuming your question is on-topic, but the Ubuntu version doesn't matter. Some commenters and downvoters there are ignorant of that fact though, I've encountered the same issue)
- https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com in some cases for a very old Ubuntu version
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions

Comment: Also [unix.se] would fit